# Sync Bitbucket master code and my Development server code

Tags: php, git, ubuntu, bitbucket

Hi I am working on a `PHP` project.
 when started my project נםאי

- local server
- bitbucket master

had the same code .

Now after some time, many developers has worked on the project and some of them have pushed code directly to the development server via `FTP` .

So now i have two different codes in development server and bitbucket, **my updated code is in development server** .

I want to add my development code to bitbucket **master** code .

What is the best way to do that , Thanks in advance

Comment: clone the project somewhere in your PC ftp the files from the server to your project and update the repo

Comment: second option is to ssh to the server git init a repo and update it from there

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to push your local code to bitbucket.

```
git add .
git commit -m "My commit message "
git push origin master
```

And now your local code is pushed to your remote on bitbucket.